# Constraining jquery mousemove events to the Y

Tags: jquery

I'm building a custom scrollbar and have so far got the it to control the scroll of a div like so :

```
var howfar = 0;
$('#scroller').mousedown(function() {

    $(this).mousemove(function(e){

        howfar += 1;
        $('#resumebox').scrollTop(howfar);
    })
});
```

This obviously is activated wheather the move moves on the x or y , how can I constrain so it only works on the Y?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just calculating how much the mouse has moved on the Y axis and use that value?

```
$('#scroller').mousedown(function(e) {

    var startMouseY = e.pageY;
    var currentScrollPosition = $('#resumebox').scrollTop();

    $(this).mousemove(function(e){

        var howfar = currentScrollPosition + e.pageY - startMouseY;
        $('#resumebox').scrollTop(howfar);

    });
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it's seems simple enough off the top of my head. You just need to get the current scrollTop value for the div you wish to scroll, and then calculate the difference between the Y position of the mousedown and the current Y position of the mousemove, then add that to the div's scrollTop position.